# JPA @Query with LIKE and UPPER %

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to run the following query in JPA hibernate @Repostiory:

```
@Query(value = "select city, state_code " +
          "from mv_city_state_center " +
          "where upper(city) like upper(:citycriteria)%",
          nativeQuery = true)
List<String> searchCityStateCenter(@Param("citycriteria") String cityCriteria);
```

In particular, the line `like upper(:citycriteria)%`.

The `citycriteria` is a partial string like `'pit'` and I want to first capitalize it to `PIT` and then put it in the `like` statement eg. `where upper(city) like PIT%` - which would match to PITTSBURGH and PITTCAIRN for example.

Hibernate accepts `like pit%` but when the `upper` is thrown in the mix, it fails for both:

- `like upper(:citycriteria)%`
- `like upper(:citycriteria%)`

What is the correct syntax for this?  For now, I'm ensuring all caller methods just pass `cityCriteria.toUpperCase()` but would prefer if the query itself handled this so callers don't have to be concerned with it.

I also tried something like below [from this guide](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-query-annotation/) to no avail.

```
public interface AuthorRepository extends JpaRepository<Author, Long> {
 
    @Query("FROM Author WHERE UPPER(firstName) LIKE %?#{[0].toUpperCase()}%")
    List<Author> findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCase(String firstName);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to fix spacing in the concatentated string. For example `state_code` and `from` would stick together in 1 word.

Comment: I updated it thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 You are using a native query, why?

2 You return a List but the projection has two columns (city, state_code)!

To concatenate two strings you can use concat:

```
@Query(value = "select city, state_code " +
          "from mv_city_state_center " +
          "where upper(city) like upper(concat(:citycriteria, '%'))"
          nativeQuery = true)
List<String[]> searchCityStateCenter(@Param("citycriteria") String cityCriteria);
```

Comment: Thank you- this worked.  I don't quite follow why `foo%` and `concat('foo', '%')` is different, but just glad it works! To answer you questions: 1) other queries in project are like this so keeping convention and also I find it difficult to troubleshoot queries if they are not in SQL.  Imagine a large query is failing - first I have to translate it into SQL and then run it in my IDE.  This is really tedious so worth the tradeoff of genericness to me...  and 2) these are returning CSV-concatenated strings like "foo, bar, baz" - and then the UI expects it that way, so I just kept the conevntion.

Comment: If you use SQL you should try jooq: https://jooq.org

Comment: I acutally did go back and change these to not be a native query after all, - thanks again for the help.